# AssemblyTitle is not shown in the Windows 7 task bar when WinForms Application is running

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-7, taskbar

Here is the strange problem on Windows 7 64-bit machine which I am not able to understand.

I have a WinForms application. It's `AssemblyInfo.cs` contains the following this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Test Application")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Test Application")]

#if DEBUG
    [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
#else
    [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
#endif

[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]

[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.000")]
```

When I right click on the `.exe` file and see the `Properties` of the file, I can see correct `File Description`.

BUT, when I run the application, **I don't see correct name (from the `AssemblyTitle`) in the Windows 7 taskbar's jump-list**. What I get there is the *namespace in which my application's `Main` method* is.
To add to the surprise, it sometimes shows correctly on some *other* Windows 7 machines.

Has anybody encountered such problem? Do we need to set some attribute other than `AssemblyTitle` for the .NET 4.0 Winform applications running on Windows 7?

Comment: What are you seeing instead?

Comment: Why should it? The main form's title is shown.

Comment: The text displayed in the TaskBar for any given app is the `Text` assigned to the Main Form of the application. Are there potentially runtime changes made to the `Text` of the form.

Comment: It does not show main form's title either. It shows just the namespace of the class containing Main method as i mentioned in the question. Btw, it shows the AssemblyTitle correctly on some Windows 7 machines!

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 8.1 64bit. It shows a namespace name. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have a shortcut to your application with this exact name somewhere on your desktop, in the start menu or pinned to your taskbar. Windows actually searches for shortcuts corresponding to the application, and will get the icon and name from here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked this as well. I have my application at one place only and no shortcut is created for it. I start my application's process from some other application.

Comment: @CSharpLearner: well, right click on your running application in the taskbar to open the jump list, right click again on the (wrong) program name, select properties and go to the General tab: if the path is pointing to your executable, it should definitely use the assembly title; if it's pointing to a shortcut, you know there was in fact one. Can you please check this?

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I have already checked that. Everything seems ok and that's why I am stumped !